# ad block plugin for firefox that blocks only specific sites

Tags: firefox, ad-blocker

Can someone recommend an add on for Firefox that will block ads only on specific site? Adblock has option only to allow specific sites, but I need the opposite of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you don't mind going through filters rather than the GUI there is a **very easy** way to do that with AdBlock Plus.

How to do it:

- Install [AdBlock Plus](https://adblockplus.org/)
- restart browser if required
- Go to Tools->Adblock Plus->Filter Preferences (or just press `ctrl-shift-F`)
- Go to Custom Filters tab
- add new rule and use this as the rule: `@@$document,domain=~sitetoenableon.ca|~sitetoenableon2.com|~sitetoenableonn.com`

This will disable ABP on all sites not listed in that rule. You can edit the rule any time through the same form to add more sites.